# How to add music player notification in API 26

Tags: java, android, android-studio, notifications, android-8.0-oreo

I've managed to show the notification but the problem is this isn't working as expected. The problems are -
1. I don't know how to keep the notification on top
2. When I slide the notification it shows snooze icon but does not show in any other music app.

Here is my code

```
`if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
                    RemoteViews expandedView = new RemoteViews(getContext().getPackageName(), R.layout.custom_push);
                    CharSequence name = "Music Player";
                    String description = "Play music in background";
                    int importance = NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_LOW;
                    NotificationChannel channel = new NotificationChannel("Music Player", name, importance);
                    channel.setDescription(description);
                    channel.setShowBadge(false);
                    // Register the channel with the system; you can't change the importance
                    // or other notification behaviors after this
                    NotificationCompat.Builder nc = new NotificationCompat.Builder(getContext(),"Music Player");
                    Intent notifyIntent = new Intent(getContext(), now_playing.class);

                    notifyIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(getContext(),0,notifyIntent,PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
                    nc.setContentIntent(pendingIntent);
                    nc.setCustomBigContentView(expandedView);
                    nc.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.notification_icon);
                    nc.setAutoCancel(false);
                    nc.setVisibility(NotificationCompat.VISIBILITY_PUBLIC);
                    nc.setOngoing(true);
                    NotificationManager notificationManager = getActivity().getSystemService(NotificationManager.class);
                    notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(channel);
                    notificationManager.notify(1, nc.build());
                }`
```

Also I've noticed that other music player don't have any notification channel in the settings. It would be great if anyone tell me how to properly implement the notification.
**Thanks**

Comment: I have same problem. My foreground notification also goes down when other normal notification comes. Did you solve the issue?

Comment: No my friend. I started developing games for android.

Answer (score 0):

According to https://developer.android.com/training/notify-user/channels ,

1) The priority of the notification only can be set using `NotificationManager .IMPORTANCE_HIGH`
2) Is necessary to know the Identifier for the other music apps channels `CHANNEL_ID`, maybe this post help you : https://medium.com/google-developers/migrating-mediastyle-notifications-to-support-android-o-29c7edeca9b7

Comment: Thanks for the link Jhoan but unfortunately it doesn't solved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

While creating the notification channel set notification importance high NotificationManger.IMPORTANCE_HIGH

```
  NotificationChannel channel = new NotificationChannel(channelId, ChannelName, NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH);
```

Comment: Using IMPORTANCE_HIGH also plays notification sound, vibrates the device and show the notification like heads up display just like a text message.

Comment: set channel.setSound(null,null); if you don't want to set sound for notification

Comment: Still not working. Its going down everytime a new notification comes while other music player always stay on top and the new notification comes below them.

Comment: have deleted the application and re install it ? try to set importance manually from notification.